# I want to add a counter and add 70 in this date 20180101 example is when counter is greater than 31 add 70 in date 20180101 else j+1

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, etl

I am setting up to add a counter in my shell script and add 70 in this date 20180101 example is when the counter is greater than 31 add 70 in date 20180101 else j+1. when we add 70 it will 20180201 again add 70 when the counter is > 31.

```
j=20180101
while [ $j -le 181231 ]
    do

            fi
j=$(( j + 1 )) #increase number by 1

 done
```

Comment: Why `>31`? There are months with only 30 days or even 27 or 28 day. `20181231` would go to `20181301` - which is also nonsense.

Comment: You may consider expression like `date --date="+1 day"`

Comment: I know this but my requirement is to add 70.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and remove tags that are not relevant - apparently, it has nothing to do with Oracle or ETL.

Comment: @kvantour, I assume he is rather looking for `date --date="20180101 +1 month"` - but the requirement is not clear.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Aha, now I see where his 70 comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cycle over a set of dates, you should not consider them to be integers, but actual dates. Even though your date string has the format `YYYYMMDD` and looks like a number, it does not have the same operations as a number. As you point out, you are in trouble when you want to increment an extra day when you are on the last day of the month, or even worse, last day of the year:

```
20190131 -> 20190201
20190228 -> 20190301
20190430 -> 20190501
20193112 -> 20200101
```

But things become really annoying when you take leap-years into account:

```
20190228 -> 20190301
20200228 -> 20200229
```

So you could set up an elaborate system that keeps track of all these things such as:

```
days_in_month=(x 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
day=20180101
while (( day < 20181231 )); do
    # start with incrementing day:
    yyyy=${day:0:4}; mm=${day:4:2}; dd=${day:6:2}
    if (( dd < ${days_in_month[$mm]} )); then
       (( day++ ))
    elif (( mm == 2 && (yyyy%400 == 0 || (yyyy%100 != 0 && yyyy%4 == 0)) )); then
         (( day++ ))
    elif (( mm < 12 )); then
       dd="01"; (( mm++ )); day="${yyyy}${mm}01"
    else
       (( yyyy++ )); day="${yyyy}0101"
    fi
    # do your stuff
done
```

or you can just keep it simple:

```
day=20180101
while (( day < 20181231 )); do
    # start with incrementing day:
    tmp=${day:0:4}-${day:4:2}-${day:6:2}
    day=$(date -d "$tmp + 1 day" "+%F")
    # do your stuff

done
```

Comment: The leap year is not simply defined by `yyyy%4 == 0` (see [Leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)) however, most likely you will not face the exception of 100 / 400 year

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I wonder if the script will still be around in 400 yr.